# Dart intl library resolving with incorrect path

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I've only just started a Dart application (using AngularDart). When I import the AngularDart package I see a console error in Dartium.

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
```

If I comment out the AngularDart import then I don't see the error.

It appears as though the `intl` library is being resolved from my `web` directory as its root. (e.g. `web/packages/intl/src/temporary_debugging.dart` instead of `packages/intl/src/temporary_debugging.dart`).

I also see this same error with an untouched version of the [AngularDart tutorial](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/index.html) so I'm wondering if this is a bug. I've played around with this tutorial before and I haven't seen this error until now.

Answer (score 0):

In describing this error I found that in using the built in server in WebStrom 8 (EAP) I see this error, but when using WebStorm 7 the error doesn't occur. I'm going to file a bug with IntelliJ.

Comment: can't recreate in WebStorm8 EAP - Dart Angular application debugging works fine for me (dart SDK 1.1.3_r32314)

Comment: can you provide a project (based on the AngularDart tutorial) that shows up the issue?

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with my WebStorm configuration. WebStorm 7 is doing the same thing now and when I run the same code on another machine from either WebStorm 7 or 8 I don't see the same issue. I'm going to see if reinstalling WebStorm fixes this issue.

Comment: I started seeing it again, but only when I launch from WebStorm (using the built in server). What I'm seeing is very similar to this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395490/intellij-suddenly-returning-403s-and-404s-for-dart-web-app